# One who attains Vishnu, for him Siva is everything - What does this mean?

Tags: vishnu, shiva

In unique commentary of Bhagwat Geeta by AchArya Abhinavgupta, he ends his commentary with the following verse. What does this possibly mean? Does any scripture explain this relation? Or talk about similar verse?

> Whatever action might be performed by a Yogin - who has freed his mind dominated by the three gunas, which are the nature of knowledge, ,confusion & inertia, **and who has attained Vishnu, who is beyond thought**, through the beauty of realization of his own self - the action is performed effortlessly because he is engaged only in such activities of the sense organs, which arise in him on their own. **To such a Yogin Siva is everything**.

Comment: Which verse of BG this commentary written on? or it's at the end of BG?

Comment: @Pandya Yes, he is ending with this verse.